# How to load Multiple XML files to MySQL using java

Tags: java, mysql

I want to load multiple Xml file's to MySQL in a single java code.
I am able to load single xml file at a time, and my code for that is given below

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        String fileName="D:\\sample.xlsx";
        Vector dataHolder=read(fileName);
        saveToMySQL(dataHolder);
    }
```

Code to read data from XML

```
public static Vector read(String fileName)    {
            Vector cellVectorHolder = new Vector();
            try{
                FileInputStream myInput = new FileInputStream(fileName);
                //POIFSFileSystem myFileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(myInput);
                XSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook(myInput);
                XSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);
                Iterator rowIter = mySheet.rowIterator();
                while(rowIter.hasNext()){
                    XSSFRow myRow = (XSSFRow) rowIter.next();
                    Iterator cellIter = myRow.cellIterator();
                    //Vector cellStoreVector=new Vector();
                    List list = new ArrayList();
                    while(cellIter.hasNext()){
                        XSSFCell myCell = (XSSFCell) cellIter.next();
                        list.add(myCell);
                    }
                    cellVectorHolder.addElement(list);
                }
            }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace(); }
            return cellVectorHolder;
        }
```

Code to write XML data to MySQL

```
 private static void saveToMySQL(Vector dataHolder) {
                String id="";
                String diagramName="";
                String startNode="";
                String endNode="";

                System.out.println(dataHolder);

                for(Iterator iterator = dataHolder.iterator();iterator.hasNext();) {
                    List list = (List) iterator.next();
                    id = list.get(0).toString();
                    diagramName = list.get(1).toString();
                    startNode = list.get(2).toString();
                    endNode = list.get(3).toString();

                    try {
                        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "welcome");
                        System.out.println("connection made...");
                        PreparedStatement stmt = con
                                .prepareStatement("INSERT INTO SampleDB(id,diagramName,startNode,endNode) VALUES(?,?,?,?)");
                        stmt.setString(1, id);
                        stmt.setString(2, diagramName);
                        stmt.setString(3, startNode);
                        stmt.setString(4, endNode);
                        stmt.executeUpdate();

                        System.out.println("Data is inserted");
                        stmt.close();
                        con.close();
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
         }
```

Is there a way to import multiple XML files to DB
How to alter this code to import multiple Xml's to MySQL DB

Comment: Did you mean XML or XLS(MS Excel) file? Also whatever the file is, just put them into a directory and read them one by one (java.io) and upload them.

Answer (score 0):

You can call more times your method:  `read(fileName);` changing the file name if the structure is equal.

Btw. in read method, you can change this:

```
while(cellIter.hasNext()){
  XSSFCell myCell = (XSSFCell) cellIter.next(); 
  list.add(myCell);
}
```

into

```
while()...
list.add(myBean)
```

with

```
public class myBean {
  String id;
  String diagramName;
  String startNode;
  String endNode;
}
```